# How to efficiently create large tables in android views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a screen which needs to contain a rather large table (14). Currently I have it defined as a TableLayout with a bunch of TableRows and TextViews. It's definitely inefficient as it means the layout has well over 150 views total. What are some other options?

Requirements:

- Each view has its own onClickListener which is set programatically when the view is first created. Maybe there's a better way to do this in XML as well.
- I need to be able to rapidly traverse the table to update background colors and text
- The text is HTML as it will sometimes be bold, uderlined, and may include an optional subscript. For example Thing, **Bold Thing** (which is also underlined), or even **Bold Thing<sub>sub</sub>** where only "bold thing" is underlined and "sub" is not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this lib yet but it looks interesting.

[evrencoskun: Android TableView](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.